# HTTP Status 404 while trying to run my servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have a dyanmic web project with a DAO FileDao in package `de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.dao;` and a servlet FileCounter in package d`e.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets;` packages respectively.
I was trying to run the servlet and changed the ports 8088 since my 8080 is already occupied with some other application. When I run this servlet I get the below error in console:

```
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting propert
y 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:de.vogella.wtp.filecounter' did not fi
nd a matching property.
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8088"]
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 380 ms
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8088"]
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
Jun 1, 2012 2:39:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 260 ms
```

This is the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message /de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter

description The requested resource (/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/servlet/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter) is not available.


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
```

Any guesses on what went wrong?

Comment: _When I run this servlet I get the below error in console_ I couldn't see any error , and what did you hit on browser, what is your app's context path, what is your servlet mapped to ?

Comment: It shows a warning, Setting propert
y 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:de.vogella.wtp.filecounter' did not fi
nd a matching property. I have updated the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Error 404 means page or resources not found.
So you just typed incorrect URL. just check URL in web.xml and the URL typed in browser.

Here, maybe `FileCounter` class is misplaced. check it too.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing the same tutorial and had the same problem. I guess it's a pretty common tutorial, so I'll leave my answer here.

In my installation, Eclipse does not create a web.xml by default. When creating a Servlet, Eclipse uses annotations for mapping. I accidentaly erased the annotation when copying the tutorial's code. I guess you did the same.

To solve it I included a @WebServlet annotation before the class. Like this:

```
@WebServlet("/FileCounter")
public class FileCounter extends HttpServlet {
...
```